# Objectivec fixed marker on center of google map ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to fix the marker in the center of the map irrespective of the location coordinates. If the user moves the camera on map I want it to keep showing up in the center without any flickering in marker and new location on that marker shows, How can I do that? Please help out.

Comment: see this https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try the below code**

```
GMSCameraPosition *cameraPosition;

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)pMapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {

        /* move draggable pin */
        if (fixedMarker) {

            // stick it on map and start dragging from there..
            if (lastCameraPosition == nil) lastCameraPosition = position;

            // Algebra :) substract coordinates with the difference of camera changes
            double lat = position.target.latitude - lastCameraPosition.target.latitude;
            double lng = position.target.longitude - lastCameraPosition.target.longitude;
            lastCameraPosition = position;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(fixedMarker.googleMarker.position.latitude+lat,
                                                                          fixedMarker.googleMarker.position.longitude+lng);
            [fixedMarker.googleMarker setPosition:newCoords];
            return;
        }

    }

    - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {

        cameraPosition = nil; // reset pin moving, no ice skating pins ;)

    }
```

Comment: Hi Basir, it's working fine, but If i move the map, marker also moved and fixed in center. But I want it to keep showing up in the center without any flickering in marker.

Answer (score 5):

**Try The Below Objective C Code**

Dont Forget To Set Delegate

```
  mapView.delegate=self;
```

Create ImageView And Add It To The Center Of The Map

```
UIImageView *pin =[[UIImageView alloc]init];
pin.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20  );  
pin.center = mapView.center;
pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"];
[self.view addSubview:pin];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:pin];
```

Then Use Delegate Method Of Google Map

```
//When You Will Scroll Map Then This Method Will Be Called
     - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)MapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {

            // Get Latitude And Longitude Of Your Pin(ImageView)
              CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( position.target.latitude , position.target.longitude);

              NSLog(@"Latitude-%f\Longitude-%f\n",newCoords.latitude, newCoords.longitude);


     [[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newCoords.latitude, newCoords.longitude) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {

             //Get Place Details
             NSLog(@"%@",[[response results]objectAtIndex:0].lines);

    }];           
              return;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

**To not move the marker**

Create a Imageview or Button(if Clickable) on the center of the GMSMapView based on frame of GMSMapView.

And If you want to get coordinates you can use `mapView.projection.coordinateForPoint`

**This will move Marker**

Find center point of google map by following code

```
let centerCord = yourMapView.camera.target 

let marker = GMSMarker(position: centerCord)
marker.title = "Hello World"
marker.map = mapView
```

Implement mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:

```
 func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
     // to remove all markers       
     mapView.clear()

    //create new marker with new center
    let centerCord = [yourMapView.camera target] 

    let marker = GMSMarker(position: centerCord)
    marker.title = "Hello World"
    marker.map = mapView


    }
```

Comment: can u tell me this line in objective c :     let centerCord = [yourMapView.camera target]  ??

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCord = [yourMapView.camera target]

Comment: Hi Jasmeet, it's working fine, but If i move the map, marker also moved and fixed in center. But I want it to keep showing up in the center without any flickering in marker.